# Regex - How to match a specific 3 letter sequence, after a given number of 3 letter sequences?

Tags: javascript, php, regex, dna-sequence, genetics

I'm studying Genetics, and was wondering how I could grab the 248th 3 letter sequence of some DNA data, I'm trying to find a regex expression to match this. The data block also has numbers at the beginning of each line that need to be excluded along with spaces, only letters are to be counted in the sequencing.
Basically every 3 **letters** is counted as one sequence, and I want to find the 248th sequence. The data is in string format as well.

```
                              atggagga gccgcagtca gatcctagcg tcgagccccc
  241 tctgagtcag gaaacatttt cagacctatg gaaactactt cctgaaaaca acgttctgtc
  301 ccccttgccg tcccaagcaa tggatgattt gatgctgtcc ccggacgata ttgaacaatg
  361 gttcactgaa gacccaggtc cagatgaagc tcccagaatg ccagaggctg ctccccccgt
  421 ggcccctgca ccagcagctc ctacaccggc ggcccctgca ccagccccct cctggcccct
  481 gtcatcttct gtcccttccc agaaaaccta ccagggcagc tacggtttcc gtctgggctt
  541 cttgcattct gggacagcca agtctgtgac ttgcacgtac tcccctgccc tcaacaagat
  601 gttttgccaa ctggccaaga cctgccctgt gcagctgtgg gttgattcca cacccccgcc
  661 cggcacccgc gtccgcgcca tggccatcta caagcagtca cagcacatga cggaggttgt
  721 gaggcgctgc ccccaccatg agcgctgctc agatagcgat ggtctggccc ctcctcagca
  781 tcttatccga gtggaaggaa atttgcgtgt ggagtatttg gatgacagaa acacttttcg
  841 acatagtgtg gtggtgccct atgagccgcc tgaggttggc tctgactgta ccaccatcca
  901 ctacaactac atgtgtaaca gttcctgcat gggcggcatg aaccggaggc ccatcctcac
  961 catcatcaca ctggaagact ccagtggtaa tctactggga cggaacagct ttgaggtgcg
 1021 tgtttgtgcc tgtcctggga gagaccggcg cacagaggaa gagaatctcc gcaagaaagg
 1081 ggagcctcac cacgagctgc ccccagggag cactaagcga gcactgccca acaacaccag
 1141 ctcctctccc cagccaaaga agaaaccact ggatggagaa tatttcaccc ttcagatccg
 1201 tgggcgtgag cgcttcgaga tgttccgaga gctgaatgag gccttggaac tcaaggatgc
 1261 ccaggctggg aaggagccag gggggagcag ggctcactcc agccacctga agtccaaaaa
 1321 gggtcagtct acctcccgcc ataaaaaact catgttcaag acagaagggc ctgactcaga
 1381 ctga
```

Any help would be fantastic! I'm pulling my hair out over this

Thankyou :)

Comment: _248th 3 letter sequence_ What is it? What are those numbers on the left?

Comment: The numbers just mean how many letters have been counted from the beginning of the genes block, this is a snippet of the block. Just ignore the numbers :) Sorry

Comment: so every 3 letters is counted as one 3 letter sequence, so I want to find the 248th 3 letter sequence, if you get me?

Comment: How are you receiving this in code format? can you share? Is it a string or an array as the key(digits) with those strings on the right as the value? What is the answer for _248th 3 letter sequence_ ?

Comment: So its a string at the moment unfortunately, I don't know the answer which is annoying, and I'm trying to not have to count 248 three letter groups, because I have to do this many times

Comment: Perhaps remove the leading numbers and remove all the whitespaces. Then repeat 247 times matching a sequence of 3 chars and capture in group 1 the 248th time `^(?:.{3}){247}(.{3})` https://regex101.com/r/Z3YCIj/1

Comment: If it is just a continuous string without whitespace and character counts, just use `substr( $sequence, (247*3)-1, 3)` or something like that.

Comment: Or include matching the whitespace chars `(?:(?:[agct]\s*){3}){247}([agct]{3})`  https://regex101.com/r/2ZXNgp/1

Comment: Using PHP's `preg_match` you could match all groups compensating for numbers and spaces 248 times and then pick the captured value; see https://regex101.com/r/51dQEh/1. Or https://regex101.com/r/I8fpqF/1 if you don't want to capture.

Comment: This kind of problem is what RE are for, and now that the OP has edited it, it needs to be opened asap, imo.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/aqDYm

Answer (score 1):

One way to match against your block of data directly, would be to compensate for numbers and spaces while matching and capturing all sequences of three characters of the class `[acgt]` for the number of times you require. Only the most recent capture will be available. Example for use with `preg_match`:

```
/\A(?:((?:[\s\d]*[acgt]){3})){248}/m
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/51dQEh/1).

In code:

```php
$re = '/\A(?:((?:[\s\d]*[acgt]){3})){248}/m';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
var_dump($matches);
```

Output (simplified):

```php
array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(...) " atgg...cgg" [1]=> string(3) "cgg" } }
```

**OR** A variation of this expression if you want to directly match the target only:

```
/\A(?:(?:[\s\d]*[acgt]){3}){247}\K(?:[\s\d]*[acgt]){3}/m
```

`\K` makes the engine remember the position of the last match, but throw away the content of that match up until that point.
See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/I8fpqF/1).

In code:

```php
$re = '/\A(?:(?:[\s\d]*[acgt]){3}){247}\K(?:[\s\d]*[acgt]){3}/m';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
var_dump($matches);
```

Output:

```php
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "cgg" } }
```

Glad to see this question re-opened. :)

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to match n-1 occurrences of the pattern followed by capturing following occurrence.

```
$pattern = '/
 (?(DEFINE)(?<sequence>(?:[a-z][^a-z]*){3})) # define a pattern for a 3 letter sequence
 (?&sequence){247} # consume 247 occurrences 
 (?<match>(?&sequence)) # match 248th occurrence
/x';

if (preg_match($pattern, $data, $matches)) {
  var_dump(preg_replace('/[^a-z]+/', '', $matches['match']));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using JavaScript,** you can remove whitespace and digits with `string.replace()` and then grab the *nth* 3-letter sequence e.g. with `string.substring()`:

```js
const data = `
                              atggagga gccgcagtca gatcctagcg tcgagccccc
  241 tctgagtcag gaaacatttt cagacctatg gaaactactt cctgaaaaca acgttctgtc
  301 ccccttgccg tcccaagcaa tggatgattt gatgctgtcc ccggacgata ttgaacaatg
  361 gttcactgaa gacccaggtc cagatgaagc tcccagaatg ccagaggctg ctccccccgt
  421 ggcccctgca ccagcagctc ctacaccggc ggcccctgca ccagccccct cctggcccct
  481 gtcatcttct gtcccttccc agaaaaccta ccagggcagc tacggtttcc gtctgggctt
  541 cttgcattct gggacagcca agtctgtgac ttgcacgtac tcccctgccc tcaacaagat
  601 gttttgccaa ctggccaaga cctgccctgt gcagctgtgg gttgattcca cacccccgcc
  661 cggcacccgc gtccgcgcca tggccatcta caagcagtca cagcacatga cggaggttgt
  721 gaggcgctgc ccccaccatg agcgctgctc agatagcgat ggtctggccc ctcctcagca
  781 tcttatccga gtggaaggaa atttgcgtgt ggagtatttg gatgacagaa acacttttcg
  841 acatagtgtg gtggtgccct atgagccgcc tgaggttggc tctgactgta ccaccatcca
  901 ctacaactac atgtgtaaca gttcctgcat gggcggcatg aaccggaggc ccatcctcac
  961 catcatcaca ctggaagact ccagtggtaa tctactggga cggaacagct ttgaggtgcg
 1021 tgtttgtgcc tgtcctggga gagaccggcg cacagaggaa gagaatctcc gcaagaaagg
 1081 ggagcctcac cacgagctgc ccccagggag cactaagcga gcactgccca acaacaccag
 1141 ctcctctccc cagccaaaga agaaaccact ggatggagaa tatttcaccc ttcagatccg
 1201 tgggcgtgag cgcttcgaga tgttccgaga gctgaatgag gccttggaac tcaaggatgc
 1261 ccaggctggg aaggagccag gggggagcag ggctcactcc agccacctga agtccaaaaa
 1321 gggtcagtct acctcccgcc ataaaaaact catgttcaag acagaagggc ctgactcaga
 1381 ctga
`

function getNthSequence(n) {
  const sequenceLength = 3
  const startIndex = (n - 1) * sequenceLength

  return data
    .replace(/\s|\d/g, '')
    .substring(startIndex, startIndex + sequenceLength)
}

console.log(getNthSequence(1))
console.log(getNthSequence(2))
console.log(getNthSequence(248))
```

---

**Using PHP,** you can remove whitespace and digits with `preg_replace()` and then split the string into an array of 3-letter strings with `str_split()`:

```php
<?php

$data = <<<DNA
                              atggagga gccgcagtca gatcctagcg tcgagccccc
  241 tctgagtcag gaaacatttt cagacctatg gaaactactt cctgaaaaca acgttctgtc
  301 ccccttgccg tcccaagcaa tggatgattt gatgctgtcc ccggacgata ttgaacaatg
  ...
DNA;

$sequences = preg_replace('/\s|\d/', '', $data);
$sequences = str_split($sequences, 3);

echo $sequences[0] . PHP_EOL;
echo $sequences[1] . PHP_EOL;
echo $sequences[247];
```

See https://3v4l.org/9mpcE for a demonstration.

---

**Addendum:**

I just noticed that you seem to be looking specifically for a regex solution. However, as can be seen in my answer, it's not necessary to use regex to match/get the *nth* 3-letter sequence, and I would argue that using `string.substring()` (in JS) or `str_split()` (in PHP) is cleaner and more readable than using a complex regex pattern. Nevertheless, regex is a valid choice for removing whitespace and numbers from the data string.